# How to use type-guard properly

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I was trying to use [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) unsuccessfully. And maybe someone can tell me how can I apply the logic I'm trying to achieve here.

I have two events and DTOs are defined accordingly, then I have one wrapper around it.

```js
enum MyEvent {
  Push = 'push',
  Forward = 'forward',
}

class ForwardDTO {
  email!: string;
  subscriptionID!: string;
}

class PushDTO {
  email!: string;
}

class EmitDTO {
  payload!: ForwardDTO | PushDTO;
  type!: MyEvent;
}

// Usage, I do convert this JSON into class instance with class-transformer but not showing it here to keep it simple
const dto: EmitDTO = JSON.parse('{"payload: {"email": "my@email.com", "subID": "aabbcc"}", "type": "forward"}');
if (dto.type === MyEvent.Forward) {
  // Obviously not working the line below, I need to typecast
  // const push = dto.payload.subID;
  const push = (dto.payload as ForwardDTO).subID; // This works, but can we do without it?
}
```

My goal is when I get `EmitDTO` with one `if` statement to get the correct type. Is this even possible?
Basically, I'm trying to get the correct type without type-casting

I tried this way

```js
class EmitDTO {
  payload!: ForwardDTO | PushDTO;
  type!: MyEvent;
  
  isForward(): this.payload is ForwardDTO {
    return this.type === MyEvent.Forward;
  }
}
```

But that is wrong, and apparently, type guard cannot be used this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can amend that type guard signature to:

```js
  isForward(): this is { payload: ForwardDTO }
```

Then there is no explicit cast required:

```js
if (dto.isForward()) {
  const push = dto.payload.subID;
}
```